# Error en trigger, solo pueda aumentar un sueldo y no disminuirlo

Tags: sql-server, trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER th_AumentoSueldo
ON Empleados
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NEWSUELDO
    IF UPDATE(Sueldo) < @NEWSUELDO
      BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      END
    ELSE
       SET Sueldo = @NEWSUELDO
END
```

Hola, tengo error en este trigger, lo que quiero que realize el que cuando quiera modificar el sueldo, solo pueda aumentarlo y no disminuirlo

Comment: Y cual es el error?

Comment: @gbianchi cuando hago la prueba y pongo un sueldo menor, me lo cambia

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos por la parte de que el trigger no tiene sintaxis correcta para ser compilado. Se declara una variable a la cual no se le asigna un tipo ni un valor. Despues tenemos un SET que se utiliza para asignar variables, pero lo tratas de usar para actualizar una columna. Para eso funciona el UPDATE que desencadenó este trigger.

Viendo los errores tan fundamentales, es necesario explicar un poco de bases de los triggers.

Existen 2 tipos de triggers DML (o sea, los que se ejecutan cuando cambias datos de una tabla): los que se ejecutan después de la instrucción y los que se ejectuan en lugar de la instrucción. Por default, se usan `AFTER triggers` (después de la instrucción) a menos de que se indique lo contrario.

Después, tenemos que tener en cuenta que los triggers usan 2 tablas virtuales: deleted e inserted. En estas tablas tenemos las filas que había antes de modificar la tabla y que ya no existe esa versión de las mismas, y las filas con los valores nuevos. Estas tablas son fundamentales para poder programar triggers útiles y que funcionen con múltiples filas a la vez.

Si queremos ver si el sueldo nuevo es menor que el anterior, tenemos que revisar el valor en ambas tablas, usando la llave primaria de la tabla. Y para hacer una validación de todo el conjunto, simplemente utilizamos la función `EXISTS()`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER th_AumentoSueldo
ON Empleados
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(  SELECT *
                FROM inserted i
                JOIN deleted d ON i.empleado = d.empleado
                WHERE i.sueldo < d.sueldo)
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

END
```